# RegEx extract all real numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex in JavaScript is returning only the first real number from a given string, where I expect an array of two, as I am using /g. Where is my mistake?

```
/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g.exec("-8.075090 -35.893450( descr)")
```

returns:

```
["-8.075090"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var input = "-8.075090 -35.893450( descr)";
var ptrn = /[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g;
var match;
while ((match = ptrn.exec(input)) != null) {
    alert(match);
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/kCm4z/

#### Discussion

The `exec` method only returns the **first** match. It must be called repeatedly until it returns null for gettting all matches.

Alternatively, the regex can be written like this:

```
/[-+]?\d*\.?\d+/g
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) gives you all matches:

```
var r = /[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g
var s = "-8.075090 -35.893450( descr)"

console.log(s.match(r))
//=> ["-8.075090", "-35.893450"]
```

Comment: Super. Alex answered why `exec` method did not work for me. But for practical purposes `String.match` is what I need in my case.